# True or False: Set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

True or False:

1. $\forall y(\exists! x)(xy = y)$: False. Because in case $y = 0,$ there are indefinite number of $x$ that $xy = y.$
2. $\sim (\exists x)(\forall y)(x \le y)$: True: meaning: for all $x,$ there exists an y such that $x > y$ (I deleted the negation to make a new equivalent statement).
3. $\{\emptyset\} - \emptyset = \emptyset$: True ? I know that
   $\emptyset \neq \{\emptyset\}$
4. $\emptyset \subseteq \{1, \emptyset\}$: True

Would you mind checking if my answers are correct? Thank you!

Comment: For the negation of $2$. you have to use "$x>y$" instead of "$x\ge y$" , but the answer of $2.$ is correct apart from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right, but you should say that there are numbers (infinitely many of them, in fact) $x$ such that $xy=y$.
2. Right, but for the wrong reasons: denying $x\leqslant y$ is the same thing as asserting that $x\color{red}>y$.
3. It's false: for *any* set $A$, $A\setminus\emptyset=A$. In particular $\{\emptyset\}\setminus\emptyset=\{\emptyset\}\ne\emptyset$. (**Note:** I use the notation $X\setminus Y$ instead of $X-Y$.)
4. It's true: the empty set is a subset of *any* set.

Comment: Since the question uses $-$ for set subtraction, why don't you also? The person asking the question is a beginner who may not know what $\setminus$ means.

Comment: I never use that notation, because it is ambiguous; think about $\{2,4\}-\{1,2\}$, for instance. But I will add a note to my answer about that.